# allow the user to select NULL from dropdownlist in streamlit

Tags: python, sql-server, dropdown

I have a streamlit app that is connected to the SQL database where there is a insert form that take user input in this form i  had includes **selectbox** that display the data extracted from the database in order to allow the user to select one of these options.

What i want is to allow the user in **selectbox** to select `NULL` or leave it empty .

The problem is that once it display the data extracted from the database it doesn't contains `NULL`  and **it add the first value as default.**

code:

```
pattern = r"(?<=')[^,]+?(?=')"
query_loc =(
               r"select distinct location "
               r"from dbo.info"
               )    
rows_loc = cursor.execute(query_loc).fetchall()
rows_loc = re.findall(pattern, " ".join([str(s) for s in rows_loc]))

loc__stb =  st.selectbox("Select location",rows_loc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, this

```
query_loc =(
           r"select distinct location "
           r"from dbo.info"
           )
```

is where the select box gets populated. And the reason why there is no null value is just because there is no location value with null in dbo.info table.

If so, you need add a null value to that select manually. So, it needs to be looking like that

```
r"select ' ' location union all"
r"select distinct location "
r"from dbo.info"
```

not sure about python-syntax though. Check it out please

UPD: you may use any other string instead of a space symbol.

Comment: while this work in sql as sql query but it did not add the value `NULL` inside the selectbox and there for the user can't select NULL or leave it empty.

any other suggestions?

thank you for your reply

Comment: @khaledM_dev  That's sad, I was sure that will solve the problem. Can you please check whether it is able to show nulls at all?  Try to use a space symbol like this ... r"select ' ' location union all" ...

Comment: your suggestion was right the `' '` add empty value thanks can i add like a string like "**unknown**" or **unavailable**

Comment: @khaledM_dev yep you can add any string you want. I'll update the answer with the space symbol then